# Tests on conditionally rendered elements not working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, vite

i´m a beginner when it comes to testing apps. I'm currently stuck with an error that i can´t figure out what is causing it. Can you guys give me a help? I basically have to test if an element will show on screen when the button is clicked or not.

**Greeting Component**

```
export default function Greeting() {
  const [changedText, setChangedText] = useState(false);

  function changeTextHandler() {
    setChangedText(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello World!</h2>
      {!changedText && <p>It's good to see you!</p>}
      {changedText && <p>Changed!</p>}
      <button onClick={changeTextHandler}>Change Text!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Tests with FAIL**

```
describe("Greeting component", () => {
  test('renders "Changed!" if the button was clicked', () => {
  
    render(<Greeting />);

    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button");
    userEvent.click(buttonElement);

    const outputElement = screen.getByText("Changed!");
    expect(outputElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('does not render "good to see you" if the button was clicked', () => {

    render(<Greeting />);

    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button");
    userEvent.click(buttonElement);

    const outputElement = screen.queryByText("good to see you", {
      exact: false,
    });
    expect(outputElement).toBeNull();
  });
})
```

**Error descriptions**

**Greeting component › renders "Changed!" if the button was clicked**

Unable to find an element with the text: Changed!. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

**Greeting component › does not render "good to see you" if the button was clicked**

```
 expect(received).toBeNull()

 Received: <p>It's good to see you!</p>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testes",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working, because you're not accounting for the fact that your `userEvent.click(buttonElement);` calls are asynchronous.

You need to wait for them to finish:

```
await userEvent.click(buttonElement);
```

Since we use `await` we also need to make the test function async:

```
describe("Greeting component", () => {
  test('renders "Changed!" if the button was clicked', async () => {
    render(<Greeting />);

    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button");
    await userEvent.click(buttonElement);

    const outputElement = screen.getByText("Changed!");
    expect(outputElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('does not render "good to see you" if the button was clicked', async () => {
    render(<Greeting />);

    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button");
    await userEvent.click(buttonElement);

    const outputElement = screen.queryByText("good to see you", {
      exact: false
    });
    expect(outputElement).toBeNull();
  });
});
```